# How to cite URL in paper (bottom of page in following way)?

Tags: citing, urls, paper

I am stuck with problem of citing a URL. Others question don't answer my question so please read. I want to cite url in way shown in picture. I have no idea how to do that and I am very new to latex.
I am not using seperate .blb fille just a one latex file.
[image]

This picture shows links exactly at the bottom of page on which paragraph is written on. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As simple as it can be:

With `\url` (from `hyperref`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Some random text taken from Wikipedia\footnote{\url{https://www.wikipedia.org/}}
\end{document}
```

Without `\url`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Some random text taken from Wikipedia\footnote{https://www.wikipedia.org/}
\end{document}
```

Comment: oh so footnote was trick. Thanks a lot man :)

Comment: You may also omit the `\url` if you want the link to be typeset with the same font as the rest of the document.

Comment: I now see citation but dont see that horizontal seperation line! How do i bring that?

Comment: The line is there by default with the `article` class. If you don't have it then you are using some package or document class that removes the line. There's no way to tell without seeing your code. Post a question with a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the footnote without the line so we can find out how to fix it for you.

Comment: Right, I just told myself while reading the question "that's not a citation, that's just a footnote.